# As2 and flex sdk

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-2

Which version of flex sdk should I use to compile AS2 based projects? Or is there an opensource alternative?

Comment: FlashDevelop includes MTASC which is the fastest AS2 compiler ever.
Why would you want to use the Flex SDK? AS3 and MXML are not compatible with AS2 in any way

Comment: I am searching compiler to use in Linux. So that why I want separate compiler without FlashDevelop. Can I use this from linux terminal?

Comment: Yes, MTASC is not tied to the IDE.  http://www.mtasc.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex (Version 2 and above) is an ActionScript 3 framework.  You won't be able to use it in an ActionSCript 2 project.

Flex 1 and 1.5 are ActionScript 2 based; however they were primarily sold as server side products and I doubt you'd be able to acquire a license today.

Comment: I'm trying to work on some older AS2 projects in IntelliJ. Wondering if there's any workaround to get syntax/error recognition working for AS2.